# angular data source filter

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a list of objects being rendered to a table , you can see the sample the screenshot. I am trying to filter data based on the  `#searchTransactionUserInput placeholder="" (keyup)="applyFilter($event)"`

You can see the data being returned from the sample screenshot which is table data source. The current issue is when I search for keyword "ron" it is returning other data that did not match the key , for example if the keyword is "ro" it should only return the user Ronnie js Renil but current it is also returning "user two"

What seem to be the issue with my current filter algo ? Any idea guys ? Thanks.

The priority of the filter or search is filter by fullName.

#table data source

table data source:

[image]

#UI

SAMPLE UI:

[image]

#html code

```html
<div class="search" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxFill>
  <mat-form-field appearance="standard" fxFill>
    <mat-label style="font-size: 12px"
      >Filter users by name, company or title</mat-label
    >
    <input
      matInput
      #searchTransactionUserInput
      placeholder=""
      (keyup)="applyFilter($event)"
    />
    <button
      mat-button
      *ngIf="searchTransactionUserInput"
      matSuffix
      mat-icon-button
      aria-label="Clear"
      (click)="clearSearch()"
    >
      <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

#tscode

```js
applyFilter(filterValue: any) {
  const data = filterValue.target.value;
  filterValue = data.trim(); // Remove whitespace
  filterValue = data.toLowerCase(); // Datasource defaults to lowercase matches
  this.dataSource.filter = data;

}

clearSearch(): void {
  this.searchTransactionUserInput.nativeElement.value = '';
  this.dataSource.filter = null;
  this._transactionUserPageEvent();
}
```

Comment: Why do you assign `data.trim()` and `data.toLowerCase()` to filterValue while you don't use this filterValue after that? and where do you specify the priority of the filter? Could you please post your complete code?

Comment: thats all the code for filtering Sir

Comment: @MernaMustafa , is there some better implementation of a filter Sir that would address my issue ?

Comment: There's numerous problems here, unrelated to filtering, especially around use of variables in the functions

Comment: @Drenai , yeah it is some part of the experiment I am trying , maybe I just forgot to remove it

Comment: why is that when I search for keyword "ro " it is returning data with no "ro" in it like on the screenshot above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. This is my working code:

```
<div *ngIf="isSearch" class="search-box-container">
<mat-form-field class="search-box-form-field">
  <mat-label>Search by Keyword</mat-label>
  <input #search matInput type="text" (keyup)="onSearchKeyUp(search)">
  <button mat-button *ngIf="search" matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="onClearClicked(search)">
    <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>
```

```
onSearchKeyUp(search: { value: any; }) {
var currentFilter = search.value;
this.dataSource.filter = currentFilter;

if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
  this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
}

onClearClicked(search: { value: string; }) {
this.dataSource.filter = "";
search.value = "";

if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
  this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
}
```

Comment: Sir,  why is that when I type or search "ro" why is that there is a result which is "user two" that is included ? there is no "ro " on that data https://imgur.com/a/H32B8cT

Comment: it should only return ronnie jr renil

Comment: Add "search" to OnInit and make it blank to start with as below.
search = '';

Comment: why is that when I type or search "ro" why is that there is a result which is "user two" that is included ? there is no "ro " on that data

Comment: When i search "ro" there should only 1 result since only "Ronnie js Renil" since "user  two" has no "ro" on it , https://imgur.com/a/H32B8cT

Comment: I think that is due to the securityRole = "Broker". What are the fields included in the datasource? Only include fields you need in the datasource. Otherwise you can change the word "Broker" and test.

Comment: but broker starts with BR right ? , this is all included , how do I dis-include or not include something to a datasource/

Comment: for example how do I exclude the securityRole ?

Comment: It's showing all matching records, not only the ones starting with the search text. Remove the field securityRole from the fields in displayedColumns.

Comment: here is how I get my data source bro https://imgur.com/a/gx0Hepp , how do I remove the security role from the object?

Comment: Add the line below to OnInit with the fields you need for filtering.
displayedColumns: string[] = ['companyName', 'fullName', 'title'];

And use it in the html table (or whatever you use)...
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;".....

Comment: I think that wont solve it , because we are filtering from the datasource and not from the columns , columns is just used if you want to display specific columns , it is not related to search

Comment: I already have added that which is   displayedColumns: string[] = ['action', 'image', 'fullName', 'company', 'roleDisplay'];

Comment: Could you please post your complete code to StackBlitz?